# Book (I think book series) about siblings being hunted because they have innate magic powers

Tags: story-identification, books, urban-fantasy

I think the cover was orange-ish. Listened to the audiobook in 2009, I think it was pretty new then, not sure though.

Remember very little detail, I believe the book starts with them not knowing they have powers or not being able to use them properly.
I think it's in a contemporary setting. And this might be completely wrong but I feel like fire had some kind of part in the story.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Do you recall what kind of magic powers they had, or why they didn't initially know they had them?

Comment: Unfortunately, kids being hunted due to having 'powers' is a very common subject, even if you add them being related.  Everything from "Escape to Witch Mountain" to "The Girl with the Silver Eyes" to "I am Number Four" plays with the idea.  If you can provide more details it will help; anything you can remember could be the key -- from a character or pet's name, to a power, to even a location.

Comment: And do you remember anything about what sort of powers they have? Is the fire you mention something they control? Can they [manifest puppies anywhere](https://www.smbc-comics.com/comic/2006-06-08)? Mind control? Telekinesis? Overall reality manipulation? Shoot optic beams from their eyes? See the monsters among us? Super=strength? Ability to reincarnate immediately on death?

Comment: Possibly ‘the secrets of the immortal Nicholas Flamel’. Book 2 (2008) has a red/orange imagery on a yellow/crème background

Comment: Thank you all for trying to help! Really appreciate it. The plot of Nicholas Flamel really does sound like it could be the one. It's not quite "clicking into place" but I will listen to it to see.
I do seem to remember this feeling of them being in great danger by more than one person, more like the whole government/society. Is that the case in Nicholas Flamel?

Nothing else is coming back to me though unfortunately, when it comes to powers etc. Definitely no puppies. Although there should be.

Thanks again!! =)

Answer (score 1):

It’s called *[Witch & Wizard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Witch_%26_Wizard_(series))* by James Patterson. It’s a series.

> The novel follows fifteen-year old Wisty and her eighteen-year-old brother Whit in a dystopian future, where people can be brought up on charges of witchcraft. The teens and their parents are charged with witchcraft despite their claims that magic does not exist. They are taken from their parents when they begin to show magical abilities after receiving a book and drum stick. The children meet The One Who Is The One, the leader of the political party the New Order. The teens are sentenced to be executed once they turn eighteen years of age.

Comment: This is much better!  Can you give us any details that explain how it matches?

Answer (score 1):

This could be *[Under the Mountain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Under_the_Mountain_(novel))* by [Maurice Gee](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maurice_Gee).

This is a 1979 novel set in Auckland, New Zealand, but made into a [movie in released in 2009](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt1275861/), starring [Sam Neill](https://www.imdb.com/name/nm0000554/?ref_=tt_ov_st). The novel was re-released at the same time and features an orange cover:

[image: 2009 Under the Mountain cover]

It has been many many years since I have read it, so I gave it a skim on Internet Archive and provide a hopefully accurate summary below:

The story tells of teenage twins Rachel and Theo, who have red hair and are recruited by an old man (Mr Jones or "Jonesy"; actually an alien, whose natural form is a flame) to fight other shape-shifting colonizing aliens known as the Wilberforces. the Wilberforce's real form are giant worm- or slug-like creatures that take over worlds and convert them into worlds suitable for habitation by their species, where nothing exists except mud, slime and stones.

Mr Jones' species had fought back against colonizing Wilberforces and exterminated almost all of them. They traced the Wilberforces to Earth and trapped them in a "spell", which the Wilberforces broke after several thousand years.

Rachel and Theo, who were unaware of their latent special abilities, are taught telepathic methods by Mr Jones and use those, along with some "magic" telepathic stones, created by Mr Jones' people as weapons to fight the Wilberforces. The story then tells of the fight and eventual defeat of the Wilberforces, which results in the eruption of at least one of [Auckland's volcanoes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Auckland_volcanic_field).

Things I think match - siblings, date of re-release, orange cover, fire (volcanoes and Mr Jones), latent special abilities siblings are unaware of.